# How do I use a regex to replace an Id in the middle of a Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I need a Regex or any other solution to replace an id in the middle of a Url (not in querystring).

Url example:

```
http://localhost:1876/category/6?sortBy=asc&orderBy=Popular
```

I want to replace - *category/6* with *category/anotherID*.

The routing thats being used is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "categories",
      "category/{categoryID}/{categoryName}",
      new { controller = "Search", action = "SearchResults", categoryID = "", categoryName = "" }
);
```

thanks

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? ASP.NET MVC? Are you using routing? Or is it just a random URL? I see that most of the questions you've asked are about ASP.NET MVC so if this is the case don't hesitate to retag and provide more details about your routes, ...

Comment: What is "etc"? Where did the number 333 came from? Do you want to redirect the user? Show a link to category 333?

Comment: Where do you want to perform this replace? Controller action, view, javascript?

Comment: category/{categoryID}/{categoryName}   would expect the user to know both ID and Name for a category and hopefully they would match ( what would take precidence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex.Replace() to replace the pattern '/category/\w+\?' by '/category/?'.

```
string newCategoryId = "333";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/category/\w+\?");
string inputString = "http://localhost:1876/category/6?sortBy=asc&orderBy=Popular";
string replacementString = string.Format("/category/{0}?", newCategoryId);
string newUrl = regex.Replace(inputString, replacementString);
```